# Clustering Analysis

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I want to perform clustering analysis on my data set.

I have a data set with 11 observations and 245 variables for each observation.

All the packages I found in R are clustering observations not variables.
I want to perform clustering analysis on variables.

How to perform clustering with variables.

Comment: A variable is made up of observations. What is the significance of a variable devoid of observations? My point is how are you going to measure the variable if it contains no observations? @Variety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `iclust()` function within the `psych` package as well as `hclustvar()` within the `ClustOfVar` package. These perform clustering of variables as opposed to clustering of observations.

Comment: There is also a `clusters()` function in the `igraph` package.

Comment: Good to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose your data.

Then your variables are observations, and observations become variables.

Comment: Transposing the data? I don't think it is statistically correct. Please explain the validity of this concept @Anony-Mousse

Comment: Why would it not be statistically correct? It does not change the values. `t()` even switches row names and column names for you.

Comment: @Annony-Mousse, thank you for the explanation. My bad, I did not check the vignette for the function `t()`. I just did and agree. It switches the row and column names, a type of reshaping.the dataset.

Comment: And it will allow you to cluster the former variables easily then, right?

Comment: Sounds like you're skeptical about your answer?

Comment: No, but you seem to not even want to try it. In my opinion this beautifully solves your question with a built-in function..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174323/discussion-between-ashish-and-anony-mousse).

Comment: Ashish is *not* the OP :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers everyone. Your answers helped me solve my problem.